# Error when trying to start Mirroring

Tags: sql-server-2012, mirroring

Thanks for looking at this, and thank you in advance for any answers!

I am attempting to start a mirroring session, but I am getting an Error 1418, which basically states that the TCP port doesn't exist. However, when I look at the SQL Logs, I am seeing a completely different error. It says that the login does not have CONNECT permissions on the endpoint.

Here is the problem, I do not know where this Login is coming from. It doesn't exist. It's never existed. It's not the login that I am using when connecting to either the Principal or the Mirror.

I can't create this login because there is a '$' in it, which again, makes no sense. Any help would be astronomically appreciated! Thank you.

[image: Below is the Screenshot of the Error I see in the logs]

Comment: What does "can't create" mean? Do you get an error message? What is it? Did you try surrounding the login name with square brackets? `CREATE LOGIN [CLUBREADY\SQL01$] FROM WINDOWS;`

Comment: Yes, it gives an error message stating that there is an invalid character.

Comment: Weird, [I was able to do this no problem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8fjHS.png). And [here is the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g2rWV.png).

Comment: Are you running the database service as LocalSystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the issue was actually related to certificates. Once the certificate was backed up and shared to the mirrored server, everything worked as intended. I just wanted to swing back around and let those who were reaching out to help know where I landed.